# How to remove multiple list items by value in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:

`a = ['a','b','c','f','w','r','q']`

I want to do something like this:

`b = a.remove['a','b','q']`

Transfer all the value of `a` to `b` variable while removing some elements.

Comment: Only by iterating through it and comparing values one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list comprehension:

```
>>> a = ['a','b','c','f','w','r','q']
>>> b = [x for x in a if x not in ['a','b','q']]
>>> b
['c', 'f', 'w', 'r']
```

Or, if your values are unique and order doesn't matter, you can use sets:

```
>>> set(a) - set(['a','b','q'])
{'c', 'r', 'w', 'f'}
```

Comment: also to use `set`s values should be hashable

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension as follows:

```
b = [
    value
    for value in a 
    if value not in ['a', 'b', 'c']
]
```

If your *exclusion list* is big, use `set` for it.

Answer (score 0):

why not create a separate list with values you want to remove and then use a loop through the second list and remove the item from the first.

```
b = ['a', 'b', 'q']
for i in b:
    if i in a:
        a.remove(i)
```